# pstricks, arithmetic, variables and lput

Tags: pstricks

I am trying to construct wiring diagrams and have made the, perhaps niave, assumption that it is better to have a few reference points (top, bottom, rhs, lhs, ...) and then position everything relative to those.  I am hoping that changes in my layout can be easily accomodated as I go along.

Here is a minimumish example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\begin{document} 
\newlength{\psutextx}
\setlength{\psutextx}{100mm}
\newlength{\psutexty}
\setlength{\psutexty}{100mm}
\newlength{\sskip}
\setlength{\sskip}{10mm}

% set posns for box titles
\setlength{\psutextx}{\psutextx+\sskip}%   %% 110mm hopefully
\setlength{\psutexty}{\psutexty-\sskip}%   %% 90mm hopefully

\begin{figure} 
\caption{Wiring in Trunk}
\begin{pspicture}
\lput(\psutextx, \psutexty){PSU}  %% I am expecting this to be 110, 90
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But latex is not happy:

! Bad number: `\psutextx '. 0 substituted..

Googling for this, people have suggested writing pure postscript, but I cannot see how to do this using variables.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to place content at some (x,y) coordinate. For that you should use `\rput` rather than `\lput`. The latter is for placing `l`abels on lines and should therefore be preceded by such a segment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document} 
\newlength{\psutextx}\setlength{\psutextx}{100mm}
\newlength{\psutexty}\setlength{\psutexty}{100mm}
\newlength{\sskip}\setlength{\sskip}{10mm}

% set posns for box titles
\setlength{\psutextx}{\dimexpr\psutextx+\sskip}%   %% 110mm hopefully
\setlength{\psutexty}{\dimexpr\psutexty-\sskip}%   %% 90mm hopefully

\begin{figure} 
  \caption{Wiring in Trunk}
  \begin{pspicture}
    \rput(\psutextx,\psutexty){PSU}  %% I am expecting this to be 110, 90
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is easier to have the unit cm. Then you can use the PostScript notation for the calculations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pst-circ}

\def\psutextx{10 }\def\psutexty{10 }\def\sskip{1 }% space is important
\begin{document} 

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](12,10)
\rput(! \psutextx \sskip add \psutexty \sskip sub){PSU}
\psdot(11,9)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The preceding `!` tells PSTricks that the following coordinates are in PostScript notation.